# groovy way of if(var) fn(var)

Tags: grails, groovy

i want to know is there any groovier way of code below:

```
def dataList = OperLog.createCriteria().list(max:params.max, offset:params.offset) {
    if(params.relationId){
      eq('relationId',params.long('relationId'))
    }
    order(params.sort, params.order)
}
```

such as  someVar?.someMethod
is there any sugar of  don't call a method where it's params is null

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same.... :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
params.relationId?.with { rid ->
  println rid
}
```

And the code inside the `with` block will not be executed if `params.relationId` is `null`...

However, I'd argue that your original code is more obvious in its intentions, and you won't have to try and work out what it is doing when you come to review it at a later date ;-)

Comment: It should be noted that due to 'groovy truth', an empty string, zero int, or false boolean would pass this test, so the with statement would execute. This is different to the behavior of the conditional example. Only if the value is null are these two constructs comparable (another reason to stick with the if statement maybe?) :-)

Answer (score 0):

is there any groovier style of this?

```
def list = [vo1,vo2,vo3]
list.each{
   someMethod(it)
}
```

just like

```
list*.toString()
```